# How to monitor an oracle schedule execution time?

Tags: oracle, listener, scheduler, monitor

I have a procedure in a package, since it might take some time, it will be called by a scheduler job run in background(dbms_job.submit). If schedule takes too long (an hour), I'll need to insert a record in a table immediately. How can I do this?  Is there an easy way? I don't want to frequently to check the scheduler_jobs table, I prefer to use something like an event lisenter to monitor its performance, as long as the execution time hits the 60 minutes, an event will be triggered.

Comment: Schedule another job that checks [`ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS.html#GUID-E87CA539-38E8-41A4-B10B-784308A56F02) table (`ACTUAL_START_DATE` or `RUN_DURATION` columns) and inserts the data you need into some table. But you may directly use this table instead.

Comment: Do you want to insert the row when the procedure has finished and took longer than one hour, or one hour after start if the procedure is not finished yet?

Comment: I'd like to insert a row no matter the procedure is end or still running. So I need a way to monitoring it. Or I can declare start time and a end time to do the minus at the end of procedure to check if it hits 60 minues.

Comment: `dbms_job` is the legacy scheduler. Be sure to use `dbms_scheduler` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-D7A11F8A-8746-4815-91C4-BC8DDBA4C74A__CIHCIDII):

> `max_run_duration`:
>
> This attribute specifies the maximum amount of
> time that the job should be allowed to run. Its datatype is `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`. If this attribute is set to a non-zero and non-NULL
> value, and job duration exceeds this value, the Scheduler raises an
> event of type `JOB_OVER_MAX_DUR`. It is then up to your event handler
> to decide whether or not to allow the job to continue.

I never used it, but looks like you have to use `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_EVENT_SCHEDULE` to listen to this event.

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_EVENT_SCHEDULE (
   schedule_name => max_execution_time_exceeded,
   event_condition => 'tab.user_data.event_type = ''JOB_OVER_MAX_DUR''');
```

Then use it to create the job which insert a record in a table immediately and optionally kills the long running job.

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name => ...,
   job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action => ...,
   schedule_name => 'max_execution_time_exceeded'
)
```

As said, so far i never used this by myself but it gives you an idea how it should work.